# Is it ok to DELETE/INSERT instead of DIFF/UPDATE when doing entity mapping?

Tags: sql, database, entity

Let's say I have an event, and I want to have people attending it.

When I create the event, I would do...

```sql
INSERT INTO event (eventName) VALUES ('some event'); -- eventId = 1

INSERT INTO eventPeopleMapping (eventId, personId) 
VALUES 
    (1, 1), -- Person 1
    (1, 2), -- Person 2
    (1, 3),  -- Person 3
    -- hundreds more...
;
```

Now, what If I want to remove `Person 3` but add `Person 7`?

```sql
DELETE FROM eventPeopleMapping WHERE eventId = 1;

INSERT INTO eventPeopleMapping (eventId, personId) 
VALUES 
    (1, 1), -- Person 1
    (1, 2), -- Person 2
    (1, 7),  -- Person 7
    -- hundreds more...
;
```

**Is this a good way to do it?**

**NOTE:** This is for hundreds of people, changing often.

Comparing arrays and objects in order to find differences, and then hunt for the values in the database is too cumbersome. This seems so simple, but I don't know if I am missing something.

The only drawback I see is **A TON** of mapping IDs, and them constantly changing.

Answer (score 0):

Your method works, but it requires knowing all the people at the event.  More commonly, you would delete only the row you want deleted and then insert only the new row:

```
DELETE FROM eventPeopleMapping
    WHERE eventId = 1 AND personId = 3;

INSERT INTO eventPeopleMapping (eventId, personId) 
    VALUES (1, ;7)  -- Person 7
```

Comment: If it is always removing one and adding another one , why don't we just `update` as one action instead `delete` and `insert` as two actions ? or am i wrong ?

Comment: Yes, I do know all the people attending at all times. Also, this use case is for hundreds of people constantly changing. So, I was wondering if my approach is bad if there are 100 people and if I add one, 100 get deleted, 101 are inserted after. This is much easier than figuring out what to delete, and what to insert, but I am not sure of the cost.

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 . . . The OP specifically says to remove one person and to add another, not to change one person into another.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Yes, and not necessarily one person. There could be 100 removed and 200 added. Does your answer stand?

Comment: @Ivan . . . To be honest, I don't understand why you are using a database if you have the complete lists somewhere else.  The database should really be tracking that information, and `insert`/`delete` would be the appropriate actions.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Sorry if I'm not making sense. Let's say Facebook events. How do they keep tracking who attends which events is my question. Many events, many constantly changing attendees. What I mean by I have the complete list is during the editing process in the app. Then I send that info to the API.